# 18.04: Playing DVD movie fails with error "missing dvd ac-3 (atsc a/52) decoder"

Tags: dvd, ac3

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to play a movie DVD I get an error message that I need to install the *dvd ac-3 (atsc a/52) decoder*.  I can't find this software and instructions on how to install it. I can play movies on the internet, hard drive, and flash drive but not the DVD player. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The video you’re trying to watch is using copyright protection technology and Ubuntu is not designed to play those videos unless you enable AC3,  a [Dolby Digital audio format](https://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/AC3-Dolby-Digital-audio-files-used-on-DVDs) for DVDs.

Run these commands to add AC3 capability for apps other than [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) (VLC already has it):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 3):

The VLC player is use full to play DVD

Comment: That solved the problem.

Comment: VLC is a great app!